# Training object detectors from scratch leads to really bad performance

Tags: tensorflow, keras, object-detection

I am trying to train a Faster-RCNN network with Inception-v3 architecture (reference paper: [Google's paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.10012.pdf)) as my fixed feature extractor using keras on my own dataset (number of classes = 4) which is very different compared to the Image-net. Still I initialized it with Image-net weights because this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.1792.pdf) gives evidence that initializing with pre-trained weights is always better compared to random initialization.

Upon Training for 60 Epochs my Training accuracy is at 96% and my validation accuracy is at 84% ,Over-fit! (severe maybe?). But what is more worrying is that my loss did not converge at all. Upon testing the network it failed miserably! like, it didn't even detect.

Then I took a slightly different approach. I did a two step training. First I trained the Inception-v3 on my dataset like a classification problem (Still initialized it with Image-net weights) it converged well. Then I used those weights to initialize the Faster-RCNN network. This worked! But, I am confused why this two staged approach works but Training from scratch didn't work. Given I initialized both the methods with the pre-trained image-net weights initially.

Is there a way to train Faster RCNN from scratch?

Comment: Unfortunately this is not a programming question, only ML/DL theorists can really answer it, and I don't think we know why it works with pre-training and not without it.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I kinda intuitively suspect the back prop through the ROI pooling layer. But am unsure.